# HttpURLConnection.inputStream empty (InputStream to Bitmap)

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to convert a googleapis map image to a Bitmap using a function below. An image is visible in the browser if enter the url address.

I'm running the function using withContext(Dispatchers.IO) to allow connection.connect() to be run in the background.

The function is called from the main scope.
connection.connect() does not throw any error.
The InputStream seems to be empty, so there is nothing to decode by the BitmapFactory.

How can I fix the code?

```
 private suspend fun convertToBitmap(venueId: String, location: LatLng, newVenue: Boolean): Bitmap {

    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        val gsmUrl: String? = getStaticMapUrl(venueId, location, newVenue)
        val url = URL(gsmUrl)
        val connection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        connection.doInput = true
        try {
            connection.connect()
        }catch (e: java.lang.Exception){
            Timber.e(e)
        }
        val input: InputStream = connection.inputStream
        val bm: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)
        return@withContext bm
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are even trying to use the input stream if you had a catch before.

Comment: Make sure your **input stream** has been fully downloaded before converting it into a bitmap.